# Posting array of strings to .net-core mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

Problem:

I am trying to send an array of strings via jquery post but they dont get parsed correctly, all I get is null in the list.

javascript:

```
var array = [];
array.push("test")
array.push("test2")
array.push("tes3")

$.post("Admin/FilteredKeys", $.param(JSON.stringify({ Ids: array, OnlyActive: true }, true)));
```

C# Model:

```
public class MySearch
{
    public bool OnlyActive { get; set; } = true;
    public List<string> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

action in controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FilteredKeys(MySearch filter)
{
    var data = await _service.GetFilteredKeyTypes(filter);
    return View();
}
```

I've googled and found that the traditional property need to be set to true but it remains the same, i tried this snippet as well:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Admin/FilteredKeys",
    data: postData,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.Result);
    },
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true
});
```

This is a .net core project do additional I need to change additional paramaters somewhere?

EDIT:

forgott to add that my original attempt was like this:

```
$.Admin.worker.postJson("Admin/FilteredKeys", JSON.stringify({ Ids: array, OnlyActive: true }), function (data) {
    var t = "";
});

postJson: function (url, data, callback) {
    $.LoadingOverlay("show");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            if (callback)
                callback(data);
            $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
        },
        error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
            //$.helpers.errorHandler($("#fileDialogErrors"), event.responseText);
            $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't give it a test but I would suggest using `data: { filter : postData }` in ajax since I faced and solved similar problems.

Comment: My sneaking suspicion is something to do with where you're parameterizing a stringified object: `$.param(JSON.stringify({ Ids: array, OnlyActive: true }`. Have you simply tried posting the object itself as the post data? e.g. `{ Ids: array, OnlyActive: true }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I believe accepted answer is not correct - here is alternative one (similar, but not the same as other answers here). First you need to decorate model with `FromBody` attribute:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FilteredKeys([FromBody] MySearch filter)
{
    var data = await _service.GetFilteredKeyTypes(filter);
    return View();
}
```

And ajax call should look like this:

```
var array = [];
array.push("test")
array.push("test2")
array.push("test3")
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Admin/FilteredKeys",
    data: JSON.stringify({ Ids: array, OnlyActive: true}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
        // ...
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this:

```
  $.post("Admin/FilteredKeys",{ Ids: JSON.stringify(array), OnlyActive: true });
```

Comment: I thought the same, Manoj :) Only thing I would say is it might benefit everyone if you explain your answer, a little.

Comment: just a basic post to the url with the parameters set in braces

Comment: @Keith - I know that. Perhaps I wasn't clear. What I meant was if it was explained *why* the existing code *doesn't* work, and how this differs, this would make the answer much more complete and understandable to all users.

Comment: It will stringify whole array into one string. So, there is no need to `JSON.stringify(array)`, only `Ids: array`.

Comment: This is one of those questions I just pulled my brain out of my head and I am asking why the JSON.stringify did not parse it 'correctly' when parsing the entire object? This works perfectly

Comment: @Manoj I've downvoted, because your solution will return to controller non empty object, but for `Ids` list it will get one item, with json serialized string of an actual array and I don't think that this is a right solution.

Comment: @SeM - same reason I've not upvoted yet. I think it would be unfair to downvote - the answer is on the right track, at least. But, I agree: This answer needs to simply pass the `array` as the value of `Ids`, rather than serializing it, which renders it not entirely correct, yet.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for the sake of the alternative (if someone will prefer this solution):

```
$.post("Admin/FilteredKeys", { Ids: array, OnlyActive: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Too be sure that the controller tries to parse the model from the body you could add the FromBody attribute:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FilteredKeys([FromBody] MySearch filter)
{
...
}
```

Also you should add a application/json content type to your request :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ...,
    data: ...,
    success: ...
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Admin/FilteredKeys",
        data: { filter: postData},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data.Result);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Thank you for your advise.